# how to sum with condition in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection named tablename like following

userid, type, class, amount

I want to get the sum of amount and the condition are userid = 5, type = 3, class = 8

My solution

```
let amountlist = await db.tablename.find({type: 3, class: 8}).then(amounts => {
    return amounts || [];
});
let allamount = 0;
amountlist.forEach(eachamount => {
    allamount += eachamount.amount;
});
```

But I don't think it reflects the efficiency of mongodb execution. What is the most efficient solution for implementation? Thank you. We

Comment: A better (efficient) way to do this is to write an aggregation query with `$match` and `$group` stages.

Answer (score 0):

- MongoDB aggregate

```js
db.tablename.aggregate([
{$match : {userid: 5, type: 3, class: 8}},
{$group: {_id : null, allamount: {$sum: "$amount"}}}
])
```

- nodejs

```js
let results = await TableName.aggregate([
{$match : {userid: 5, type: 3, class: 8}},
{$group: {_id : null, allamount: {$sum: "$amount"}}}
]);
let allamount = results[0].allamount;
```

*Make sure you have compound index on 3 fields above to improve aggregation's performance.*